# curl --data-urlencode different from linux to windows

Tags: linux, windows, curl, urlencode

I have a curl command using --data-urlencode. Executing it in a linux terminal give the expected result, but executing it from a windows 7 shell encodes different when using special characters like æøå. linux terminal is UTF-8. Any clues how to get windows behave ?

Comment: Okay, in the case of 'æ' windows return "%E6" and linux returns "%A6"

Comment: Oh , it is "%E6" and linux returns "%C3%A6" ie a case if ascii to utf8